enter a long condition below 30 pips of the first long trade
var float entryPrice = na
if (long_condition)
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (long_condition)
entryPrice := close // Set entry price when the long condition is met

// Check if the price is below 30 pips from the initial entry
if (not na(entryPrice) and close < entryPrice - 0.0030)
strategy.entry("Long2", strategy.long)

hi, i am working on pinescript. im new to coding . i am a chemical engineer by profession. but building my own strategy. i need this help.for example my long trade has been executed at (1.0850 eurusd). and now  price is 30 pips (1.0820) below from my entry price.how can i enter another long trade from this point. after 30 pips.please guide me it can be after 30 pips of the entry price or the candle close after entering long thankyou.

By default Tradginview will place market orders. That means, you will enter a trade whenever a bar is closed or on the open of next bar (depending on your settings).
Now, if you do:
if (not na(entryPrice) and close < entryPrice - 0.0030)
    strategy.entry("Long2", strategy.long)

This is a conditional market entry. You are essentially saying, if the price closes 30 pips lower than the first entry, enter a trade. You are not saying enter a trade 30 pips lower than the first entry. There is a difference. The way you are doing will use market orders. However, you need to specify the entry price with a limit order.
To do that, you can use the stop or limit arguments of the strategy.entry() function.

strategy.entry(id, direction, qty, limit, stop, oca_name, oca_type, comment, alert_message, disable_alert) → void
limit (series int/float) An optional parameter. Limit price of the order. If it is specified, the order type is either 'limit', or
'stop-limit'. 'NaN' should be specified for any other order type.
stop (series int/float) An optional parameter. Stop price of the order. If it is specified, the order type is either 'stop', or
'stop-limit'. 'NaN' should be specified for any other order type.

Here is how to do it in your case:
entry_target = entryPrice - 0.0030

if (not na(entryPrice))
    strategy.entry("Long2", strategy.long, limit=entry_target)

Note: You need to reset entryPrice at some point (whenever a trade is closed or you go short etc.).
A second note would be, by default, you can only have one open trade in the same direction. If you want to have more than one trades (in the same direction), you should increase your pyramiding number via the Properties tab or add the setting in your strategy() call.
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding=2)


